# Receiving messages through a socket

Tags: c#, sockets

In c# when simulating a lan-messenger I am using the loopback address just for testing the current code and am being able to receive the first message I am sending.However after that there aren't any messages reaching the socket.Is there anything to do with clearing a socket buffer?.please help
This is the callback function when a connection is made:

```
private void accepted(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        Socket server = (Socket)iar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = server.EndAccept(iar);
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                client.BeginReceive(receive, 0, receive.Length, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(rec), client);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("arguments incorrect in begin-receive call", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error in accessing socket while receiving", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("socket closed while receiving", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error while receiving", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

        }
```

This is the callback function when the begin-receive method is executed:

```
void rec(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

        StringBuilder receivedData;
        //String oldvalue;
        Socket remote = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int recv = remote.EndReceive(ar);
        receivedData = new StringBuilder(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive, 0, recv));
        //MessageBox.Show(receivedData.ToString(), "received", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.textBox1.Text);
        sb.AppendLine(receivedData.ToString());
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString(); });

        }
        remote.Close(5);
        return;
    }
```

Does it have anything to do with a stringbuilder or string datatype for assigning the data received to a variable.

Comment: Please supply code for both sending and receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 2-part tutorial on C# socket programming, with source code...

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-I/1/

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Socket-Programming-in-C-sharp-Part-II/

What is wrong depends entirely on your design.  Are you polling?  Or, are you waiting for events?

The source is the download.zip file attached to this page:
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3918/socket-programming-in-c-part-1/

Comment: I do not think that is needed.I am sure its a simple code that must be added. I am receiving the first message sent.However after that, no message is coming in.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this.  Notice how WaitForData calls itself.  This allows the second, and subsequent messages to be received.

You never wait for more data.

```
    private void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        m_Client = m_Listener.EndAccept(asyn);
        WaitForData();
    }
    private void WaitForData()
    {
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        m_Client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived), null);
    }
    private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        int iRx = 0;
        iRx = m_Client.EndReceive(asyn);

        if (iRx > 0)
        {
            PacketReceiver.BytesReceived(buffer);
        }

        if (m_Client.Connected == true)
            WaitForData();
    }
```

Comment: I tried to make my code as similar to this as possible..Nothing seems to be working.I think its some logical error.
Is there anyway I can get some help.
Messages are coming in the 1st time.Nothing after that.

Comment: I think I understand what is going on.. The begin-accept method is being called only once. Apart from using threads, is there anyway tat I can make that asynchronous call to begin-accept continuously?

Comment: AFAIK, you only call BeginAccept once for a one-to-one communication.  That would have nothing to do with receiving more than one message.

Are you sure you're BeginReceive more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call BeginReceive in your rec method:

Here is what your code should be:

```
void rec(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  StringBuilder receivedData;
  //String oldvalue;
  Socket remote = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
  int recv = remote.EndReceive(ar);
  receivedData = new StringBuilder(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receive, 0, recv));
  //MessageBox.Show(receivedData.ToString(), "received", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.textBox1.Text);
  sb.AppendLine(receivedData.ToString());
  if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString(); });

  }
  remote.BeginReceive(receive, 0, receive.Length, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(rec), remote);
  //remote.Close(5);
  return;
}
```

Of course this code does not close the socket instead will wait for more data. If in your send method you are creating different socket for each message then you need to call BeginAccept instead of BeginReceive.

Hope it helps